# Handle Custom Event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react to create a contact list. I'm fetching the data in `home.js`, then sending the data as the prop to a component named `contactList.js`.
In `contactList.js` I've the data and some buttons to perform actions like edit and delete.

Whenever I click on delete it deletes data from server but the DOM is not updating.
I want to perform a custom event to update the DOM when I delete something.

Here is the component `contactList.js`:

```js
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    const ContactList = ({ contacts, title }) => {
    
        const contactDelete = (id)=>{
            fetch('http://localhost:8000/contacts/' + id, {
                method: 'DELETE'
            }).then(() => {
                console.log("deleted")
                // this.$emit('delete', id)
            }) 
        }
        return ( 
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <h4>{ title }</h4>
                <Link to={`/contact/create`} className="waves-effect waves-light btn right"><i className="material-icons left">add</i> New</Link>
                <table className="responsive-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Index</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {contacts.map((contact, index) =>(
                        <tr key={index}>
                            <td>{ index + 1 }</td>
                            <td>{ contact.name }</td>
                            <td>{ contact.email }</td>
                            <td>{ contact.phone }</td>
                            <td>
                                <Link to={`/contact/details/${contact.id}`}><i className="material-icons green-text">visibility</i></Link>
                                <Link to={`/contact/edit/${contact.id}`}><i className="material-icons blue-text">edit</i></Link>
                                <span onClick={()=>contactDelete(contact.id)}><i className="material-icons red-text">delete</i></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
         );
    }
    export default ContactList;
```

Here is `home.js`:

```js
    import useFetch from '../composables/useFetch';
    import ContactList from '../contacts/ContactList';
    
    const Home = () => {
        //State Hook
        const {data: contacts, isLoading, isError} = useFetch('http://localhost:8000/contacts'
        )
        const handleDelete = (id)=>{
            contacts.filter( contact => contact.id !== id )
        }
    
        return (  
            <div className="container">
                <div className ="card">
                    <div className ="card-content">
                        { isError && <div>{ isError }</div> }
                        { isLoading && <div>Loading...</div> }
                        { contacts && <ContactList contacts={ contacts } delete={handleDelete} title="Contact List"/>}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
     
    export default Home;
```

Comment: I think you are missing some local state to represent your "source of truth". The fetch should update the local state and when an element is deleted it should be deleted locally as well as in the back end. Alternatively you can delete in the backend and re-trigger a data fetch to ensure your UI has the latest data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not call the delete prop(handleDelete) after the data has been deleted from the server to update on the client, I will suggest that you rename the prop to handleDelete because delete is a javascript keyword

const contactDelete = (id)=>{
fetch('http://localhost:8000/contacts/' + id, {
method: 'DELETE'
}).then(() => {

```
          //update on the client here
          delete(id) // change to hanldeDelete(id)

            console.log("deleted")
            // this.$emit('delete', id)
        })
```